# Can you or can you not instantiate an interface?

Tags: java, android, instantiation

Not sure I understand.. I've been taught you can't instantiate an interface, but when I use the LocationListener interface I write:

```
locationListener = new LocationListener() {
            @Override
            public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {}
```

This works how it's supposed to, but is this not instantiating an interface? I'm not really sure I get it...

Comment: That is instantiating an anonymous class which implements the interface: see https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/anonymousclasses.html. Try printing `locationListener.getClass()`: you will see it is not `LocationListener`, but more likely something like `YourClassName$1`.

Comment: Ah ok thanks for clearing that up.

Answer (score 0):

Elaborating on Andy's comment:

If you write something like

```
final int myLocal = ...;
locationListener = new LocationListener() {
    @Override
    public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
        doSomething(myLocal);
    }
};
```

it's a shorthand for

```
class YourClassName$1 implements LocationListener {
    private final YourClass enclosingInstance;
    private final int myLocalCopy;
    YourClassName$1(YourClass enclosingInstance, int myLocal) {
        this.enclosingInstance = enclosingInstance;
        this.myLocalCopy = myLocal;
    }
    @Override
    public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
        doSomething(myLocalCopy);
    }
}
```

and then

```
final int myLocal = ...;
locationListener = new YourClassName$1(this, myLocal);
```

(The names I used will probably not match those generated by your compilation)

The shorthand silently compiles to a new class (with a name illegal for normal Java source code) and instantiates that, passing the enclosing instance (plus any local variables referenced in your methods) into the new instance by means of constructor parameters.

So, it's a plain old class that gets instantiated, and not an interface, only this class has not been written by you, but silently by the compiler when encoutering such a language construct.